# Do people say "I & you" or "me & you" when they hate each other?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I was taught that we should always put ourselves last to make our sayings more polite.

For example,

"**You & I should discuss this problem**" ("you" first & "I" last makes it more polite)

"**This is for you & me**" ("you" first & "me" last makes it more polite)

However, when watching an American movie, I heard a lady said to a man "**This is for me & you**" (they were fighting at that moment)

So,

Do people say "I & you" or "me & you" when they hate each other?

Comment: Well, few people think about etiquette when they are in a scrap. At least the sentence is grammatical.

Comment: It's simple politeness to mention the other person first, "you and me".  Otherwise if's perfectly grammatical to do it the other way around, whether you like them or not.

Answer (score 5):

"I and you" is [extremely rare](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+and+you%2Cyou+and+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20and%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20and%20I%3B%2Cc0), and you should never use it. It is not *impolite* to say "I and you"; it is simply a grammatical error. As far as I can tell from [searching Google Books](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+and+you%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1977,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=L7djWLL2HcjgwALvyYSwDg), "I and you" is *never* used as the subject of a sentence; all the hits are fortuitous, such as

> Doesn't it strike you as strange that I am I and you are you? ([link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iNfuF8rs7qkC&pg=PA1&dq=%22I+and+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjg_ar8-ZbRAhVVOVAKHXrmAuoQ6AEIMzAE#v=onepage&q=%22I%20and%20you%22&f=false))

We say "you and me" [about five times as often as we say "me and you"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=me+and+you%2Cyou+and+me&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cme%20and%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20and%20me%3B%2Cc0), so a non-native speaker should use this variant; but there is no difference in meaning that I can discern.

Comment: If you look through further pages on Google Books, you can find genuine examples of "I and you": https://books.google.com/books?id=V17JAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA16&dq=%22i+and+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpnLyT_pbRAhXhz1QKHWE3DP04KBDoAQhGMAg#v=onepage&q=%22i%20and%20you%22&f=false, https://books.google.com/books?id=2krqs2EMmz0C&pg=PA124&dq=%22i+and+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpnLyT_pbRAhXhz1QKHWE3DP04KBDoAQhMMAk#v=onepage&q=%22i%20and%20you%22&f=false...

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=MuVHh60YC4UC&pg=PA113&dq=%22i+and+you%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiD4Yio_pbRAhWoiFQKHR3zCCU4MhDoAQgpMAM#v=onepage&q=%22i%20and%20you%22&f=false

Comment: I agree with the answer overall, though I think the quote itself would actually be more grammatical if it was "... strange that I am me ...".

Answer (score -6):

No, you were taught correctly, when you are about to refer to 2 people, including you, your noun (*I / ME*) must be placed after the other one, no matter the situation, that's the main rule, and it is *interchangeable* in any situation.

But it isn't a surprise, coming from an American movie, it's totally normal, specially if it's a movie about poor people, their english grammar is usually bad-studied.

Comment: The matter is not quite this clear-cut. See this [Grammarphobia post](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2008/12/me-first.html) for an alternative viewpoint.

Comment: Also, see the comments on this ELU question: [Object pronoun: me and John, or John and me?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/244340)

Comment: @sumelic Sorry, I don't work with alternative grammar, I work with the real one, and the most proper. Of course using "Me and John" will not be a BIG deal, but we are talking about grammar, and this is what the grammar says, when referring to you and someone else, the other noun must be placed first, it's a polite question

Comment: What source do you accept as authoritative for proper grammar? I cited the blog Grammarphobia, which I think takes a fairly standard prescriptive view of grammar (note that the author says that "I" is incorrect when the pronoun is not the subject of a sentence) and the linked ELU question has a comment by the linguist John Lawler saying "Which person of two conjoined people is mentioned first is a political problem and no part of grammar." If you know of authoritative references that say this is a matter of grammar, please cite them...

Comment: It's a polite question, saying "I and you" isn't necessary wrong, but it's rarely used, as mentioned above, and if he is in a job interview or something like this, using "I and you" would probably ledd him to some consequences

Comment: Well, I'd agree with your last comment, but I downvoted your answer because it says "your noun (I / ME) must be placed after the other one, no matter the situation". This conflicts with what you just said, that "'I and you' isn't necessary wrong". (By the way, I agree with TonyK that for some reason, "I and you" seems much closer to being ungrammatical than "me and you".)

Comment: I emphasized that so that the OP would be alert about it, this will change in no situation, "You and I" will always be correct, but of course saying "I and You" isn't a big deal, specially if you are speaking nowadays, where people seem not to have learnt grammar

Comment: @Davyd: "I and you" _is_ a big deal; it will immediately mark you as an ignorant foreigner. It is not something a native English speaker would ever say. It has nothing to do with politeness; it is a language error.

Comment: @David: I think you're conflating "grammatically correct" and "idiomatically established". ***I and you*** is grammatical when used as as subject (not as object), but it's not idiomatic, so native speakers would rarely if ever either use or *encounter* it. In the context of a *learners'* site, that means it potentially ***is*** a "big deal, because it tells the audience that the speaker probably hasn't been exposed to a great deal of *conversational* English from native Anglophones (or doesn't pay much attention to the details).

Comment: @FumbleFinger yeah, it may be considered as "idiomatically established", there may be not grammatical rules for this, but it acts like if there was

Comment: Also, the idea that "poor people" usually have "bad-studied" grammar is somewhat misplaced. I don't know how good your English accent is, but (assuming he can actually read) even the poorest native speaker would instantly recognise you an a *non-native* speaker from your last comment above, simply because idiomatically that would be *not a big deal to **say** "I and You" nowadays*, not ***speak***. My point being that "grammar" is a loosely-defined concept anyway, and it's nonsensical for an nns to argue with native speakers about what is or isn't idiomatic.